# Trouble adding CEWP to a View within a Publishing Library

Tags: web-part

I have a publishing site, and we have been trying to customize the views a little bit.  We have added a CEWP to the page.  I keep getting this error though, and I'm not sure where to look.

"Unable to add selected web part(s). The file is not checked out. You must first check out this document before making changes."

Since it is a view the page cannot be checked in or out.

Default master pages are still in play, no modifications there.

Thoughts?

Comment: It is not recommended to use CEWP in publishing site for many reasons like it stores URLs as absolute URLs, does not have version history, etc. more about it at http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2009/02/01/Blocking-the-use-of-the-Content-Editor-Web-Part-in.aspx

Comment: Hadn't heard that before, but that makes sense.  This effort was one of those where we tried to take short cuts.  Shortly after this post we scrapped that path and decided to develop a layout specific to the categories instead of using the view pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking it out using SP Designer.

Comment: Well that worked.  It is very strange since we hadn't had to check it out before for the other 10 sets of changes.  Since the views don't have content approval, and it cannot be done through the interface it didn't occur to me to do it in SPD.  

Thanks!